# CSP header not detected

Tags: content-security-policy, nonce

For some reason both Mozilla Observatory and CSP validator are not detecting the CSP header in my .htaccess file yet the header is visible when viewed through Chrome.

Here's my current CSP header in my .htaccess file;

```
Content-Security-Policy: script-src 'nonce-$RANDOM' 'strict-dynamic' 'unsafe-inline' object-src 'none'; base-uri 'none'; report-uri https://altfit.report-uri.com/r/d/csp/enforce;
```

Also I noticed that the nonce is not working, inline scripts still load without nonce in place but if I make modifications to the CSP it can restrict script execution and the display of inline elements.

Info:
Server is Light Speed.
PHP version is 7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue by modifying the line in .htaccess to the following;

```
 Header set Content-Security-Policy: "default-src https: 'unsafe-inline'; report-uri https://altfitcom.report-uri.com/r/d/csp/enforce;"
```

Only issue now is the addition of unsafe-inline but from what I have read strict-dynamic and nonce do not work as a cross platform solution and I have to have inline js for some onclick events.